# Google API Map Zoom

Tags: android, dictionary, zooming

```
 import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
 import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class Map2Activity extends MapActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
MapView map;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mvMain);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
 }
```

Manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:apiKey="01VR0PIBfyfgbR5DlOlcEBPG9F5WfE7ZBPg"
             android:tag="@+id/mvMain"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i am not getting the map with these two statements (forcebly closing the app)
 map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mvMain); 
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
if it has to work what do i need to give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
android:tag="@+id/mvMain"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/mvMain"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it:--main.xml--

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/mapView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:enabled="true"
                android:clickable="true" android:apiKey="0zWsBUUrp7PHyoVnmV5qN5nHhXhZ-VJHhlnjYig" />
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Use it in your activity--

```
  LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
```

Hpoe it will help you..